# Magento2: How can I get the query sent from Magento to SQL

Tags: magento2, database

I'm trying to update a customer from Magento.

I have some issues with the data that actually is modified in the database.

The code that saves the user is :

```
$this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```

Is there a way to get the actual SQL query sent from Magento to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to log all sql queries on log file to retrieve the insert/update query, check on this link : 
https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/database-query-logging-in-magento-2